# How tp undefining variables in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In the Makefile manual, version 4.3 section 6.9

it shows the followings:

```
foo := foo
bar  = bar

undefine foo
undefine bar
```

I put the content in the Makefile and type make (the code does not have indentation at the beginning of each line)

I see Makefile:4: *** missing separator.   Stop.

Since I am using 3.81 version make, I also checked the Makefile manual of that version and I believe this is supported.

I wonder if there is anyone know the answer for this simple Makefile mistake.

Thanks.

KT

Answer (score 0):

`undefine` was added in GNU make 3.82, released over 11 years ago.

See [the NEWS file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS#n387) description of [this feature](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/NEWS#n476).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a fool of myself:-)